# How to insert hashed password in mongodb database using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb

When I inserted my hashed password to my MongoDB database using pymongo it creates a new document into a password. In this document, it creates a key called "$binary".

{

```
"_id" : ObjectId("......"),

"email" :"example@gmail.com",

"password" : {"$binary" :"JDJiJDEyJEdwNWtlY3NTSllNR0FzaGRKKHVH0Ykh4TS5JZk00SFA5SWZ2cmpWMXpKelQ2Z2hyTjQzRkNuODMy", "$type" : "00" }
```

}

I want to store my hashed password like a string. Is it possible ?? If no, So how can I get this value(hashed password) for login etc? If yes, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the hashlib libary:

```py
hasher = hashlib.md5()
hasher.update(your_string)
your_dict['hash'] = hasher.hexdigest()
```